# БД возвращает 0 записей из-за подзапроса (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть 2 таблицы:

1. `products` - содержит 2 столбца: `id`, `name`
2. `products_to_products` - нужна для отношения многие ко многим, в ней сохраняются похожие товары. Содержит столбцы: `id`, `product1_id`, `product2_id`

Мне нужно с помощью одного запроса к БД получить все товары, которые есть в БД, а так же похожие товары. Я делаю это так:

```
SELECT 
    products.*,
    (SELECT array_agg(products_to_products.product2_id)
        FROM products_to_products
        WHERE products.id = products_to_products.product1_id) as similar_products
FROM products, products_to_products
GROUP BY products.id
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Это отлично работает, если в таблице `products_to_products` есть хотя бы одна запись (неважно какая). Но как только в таблице `products_to_products` становится 0 записей, то этот запрос возвращает 0 продуктов (хотя в таблице `products` записи есть). Почему так происходит и как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Крайне не рекомендую использовать запятую
во `FROM`. Потому что это скрытый
`CROSS JOIN` с парой отличий, и такие вещи не должны
быть настолько незаметными. Ваша же изначальная задача решается
как-то так:

```sql
WITH similar_products AS (
  SELECT products_to_products.product1_id AS id
       , ARRAY_AGG(products_to_products.product2_id) AS similar
    FROM products_to_products
   GROUP BY products_to_products.product1_id
)
SELECT products.*
     , similar_products.similar
  FROM products
        LEFT JOIN similar_products
       USING (id)
 ORDER BY products.id DESC
;
```

Comment: Когда начинал изучать SQL относился к нему, как чему-то невероятно простому. По ходу использованию понимаю, что некоторые языки программирования легче учить и использовать, чем SQL :D

Comment: @Inventor  Изучайте дальше, и вернётесь к пониманию его простоты :-) .